# Editing MS word documents programmatically using Aspose

Tags: c#, ms-word, aspose.words

While editing of MS Word documents programmatically needs office installed on the server, how does Aspose do this even without having word installed?

Comment: This is no where near an answer, but read up on Open XML (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML). You do not need MS Word installed on server because the document is just a compressed range of xml-documents.

Comment: and because of that, there are tools available for most programming languages (eg C#/.NET: Open XML SDK; Java: docx4j or POI)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files like doc, docx, pdf, xls etc are either in binary or XML format. Generally they require a program like MS Office, Open Office, Adobe Reader etc. But these companies have made the structure of these files available to public. For example check [File format specifications by Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg134032.aspx).

Components like Aspose.Words are built to work with these binary/XML files specifications. That's why they do not depend on any other software installed on the server like Microsoft Office or Adobe Reader etc.

Generally, you have the following choices to edit these files.

1. Install a program like MS Office, Open Office, Adobe Reader/Pro. They offer programming using macros or automation. You must have software installed on the system.
2. Use an API that does not require any kind of software installation. [Open XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854%28v=office.15%29.aspx) and [Apache SDKs](http://poi.apache.org/) are open source. [Aspose](http://www.aspose.com/.net/total-component.aspx), however is commercial. SDKs are generally much faster, as they work directly on the source file.

Disclaimer: I work as Developer Evangelist at Aspose.